# y and x intercepts with holes

Tags: rational-functions

I am solving for the intercepts of a rational function. It has a root of (0,0) which would be an x and a y intercept, however there is also a hole at this location. If the function is undefined (because of a hole) at an intercept, does the intercept not count?

Comment: If it's undefined there then it has no intercept there.

Comment: How does it "have a root of $(0,0)$" if it has a "hole" there? To be a root requires $y$ to be $0$. But to have a hole means that $y$ is undefined. $y$ cannot be both $0$ and undefined.